# What is the preferred data type for audio/video track length?

Tags: mysql, audio, jquery-ui-sortable, sqldatatypes

The app retrieves audio tracks and uses a service to get the length of the track, in `hh::mm:ss` format.
since it's formatted as time, but it's not an actual valid time value, I need some sortable representation of the data.

1. What is your recommendation?
2. How can it be sorted/searched/filtered?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is : using the `time` dataType...
it's an actual time representation field.

Answer (score 3):

- Bring the formatted value to an `int`-Value. So: 00h 01m 30s => 90s
- Now you can sort it, search and filter without limitation!

Comment: Thanks, this is well known. I try to avoid data conversion for each field since I need to display (sometimes) more than 1000 records, sorted, at the same screen.

Comment: This conversation shouldn't be the bottleneck.

Comment: 1,000 conversions x 600 hits a second? at server-side it's not a negligible consideration.. as client-side, when used on smartphones (40% of clients), big problem..

Comment: If it's so highly hit, then cache the result of conversation. Or remember the formatted string and the underlaying integer value.